# Error message starting rsyslog after configuring system logging without journald on RHEL 7

Tags: logs, rsyslog, systemd-journald

I followed this procedure from Red Hat website https://access.redhat.com/articles/4058681 to configuring system logging without journald but after reboot rsyslog failed to start.

1. edit the /etc/rsyslog.conf rsyslog configuration file; turn "on" use
   of imuxsock local messages, comment out the loading of the imjournal
   module and uncomment the loading of the imklog module:

```
module(load="imuxsock"                 # provides support for local system logging (e.g. via the logger command)
SysSock.Use="on")
# module(load="imjournal"             # provides access to the systemd journal
# StateFile="imjournal.state")        # file to store the position in the journal
module(load="imklog") # reads kernel messages (the same are read from journald)
```

2. edit the journald configuration at /etc/systemd/journald.conf;
   switch journal to in-memory only mode and enable forwarding:

```
[Journal]
Storage=none
ForwardToSyslog=yes
```

3. create drop-in for the rsyslog unit configuration file at
   /etc/systemd/system/rsyslog.service.d/override.conf with the
   following content to ensure socket creation and linking:

```
[Unit]
Requires=syslog.socket

[Install]
Alias=syslog.service
```

When I tried to manually start it, I got following error messages

```
A dependency job for rsyslog.service failed. See 'journalctl -xe' for details.
```

But it seems rsyslog daemon started ok

```
$ sudo systemctl start rsyslog | grep Active
A dependency job for rsyslog.service failed. See 'journalctl -xe' for details.

$ sudo systemctl status rsyslog | grep Active
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2020-10-24 01:19:37 EDT; 3s ago

$ sudo systemctl stop rsyslog | grep Active
$ sudo systemctl status rsyslog | grep Active
   Active: inactive (dead) since Sat 2020-10-24 01:19:54 EDT; 2s ago

$ sudo systemctl start rsyslog | grep Active
A dependency job for rsyslog.service failed. See 'journalctl -xe' for details.
$ sudo systemctl status rsyslog | grep Active
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2020-10-24 01:20:07 EDT; 3s ago
```

journalctl -xe shows following info the date is the day I configured system logging without journald

```
Oct 16 14:20:34 systemd-journal[89]: Journal stopped
-- Subject: The journal has been stopped
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- The system journal process has shut down and closed all currently
-- active journal files.
```

any idea why rsyslog did not start during reboot, started OK manually but gave that error message?

Comment: Your link to redhat is only available to customers. Please add to your question a short description of what you did, without copying the redhat article.

Comment: Details of what has been changed is added

Comment: Is `/etc/systemd/system/syslog.service` a symbolic link to the `rsyslog.service` unit?  Also, I have seen examples which say use `module(load="imuxsock" SysSock.Use="off" Socket="/run/systemd/journal/syslog")`